# Prove the sequence converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the sequence $\left\{\frac{n}{(n^2+1)}\right\}$ convergent? If so, what is the limit.
If limit exists prove it or prove that it is divergent.

I know that as $n\rightarrow \infty$ the limit is zero. My problem is proving it.

So how do I start this: Let $\epsilon>0$, then there exists an $M$ element $N$ such that $M\le n$. So...

Can someone that is knowledgeable with Analysis help me with this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use the fact that $0\lt \frac{n}{n^2+1}\lt \frac{1}{n}$ to simplify calculations. If $N\gt 1/\epsilon$, and $n\gt N$, we automatically have $|n/(n^2+1)|\lt \epsilon$.

Comment: |n/(n^2+1)-0|=|1/n|<=1/M<epsilon?

Comment: Should be divergent even though the limit is zero (a necessary but not sufficient condition for convergence). Why? Use the integral test and you should get something along the lines of $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \text{log}(x^{2}+1)$ which is divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any positive integer $n$, we have
$$0\lt \frac{n}{n^2+1}\lt \frac{1}{n}.$$

We want to show that given any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is an $N$ such that if $n\ge N$, then $\left|\frac{n}{n^2+1} -0\right|\lt \epsilon$.

Let $N$ be the smallest integer $\ge \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. If $n\ge N$, then
$$\left|\frac{n}{n^2+1} -0\right|\lt \frac{1}{n}\le \frac{1}{N}\le \frac{1}{1/\epsilon}=\epsilon,$$
and we are finished.

**Remark:** To put it more concretely, we want to show that (among other things) if we go far enough out, then $\left|\frac{n}{n^2+1} -0\right| \lt 10^{-6}$. Well, $\frac{n}{n^2+1}$ is positive and less than $\frac{1}{n}$. So if $n\ge 10^6$, then $\left|\frac{n}{n^2+1} -0\right|\lt 10^{-6}$. We are just making formal your correct intuition that for big $n$, the number $\frac{n}{n^2+1}$ is real close to $0$.

Comment: I was somewhat close. Haa haaa...Thank you André. You were a big help.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, you were close to the end, I thought I would write it up fairly formally, as a guide. The comment by Chris K has to do with the fact that the **series** $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+1}$ diverges. That is true, but your question appears to be about whether the **sequence** $\frac{n}{n^2+1}$ converges.